# deleting a line of text from a document using terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, scripting

So in terminal, if I create a document and then add a line of text what command do I use then to delete that line of text from the document? See below for more info:

```sh
touch test.doc 
echo "this is a test" >> test.doc
```

Now what do I do if I want to delete that line ("this is a test") of text?

Comment: Do you have a terminal running on your `iOS` device?

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i '$ d' test.doc
```

- `-i` means directly modify the file, i.e test.doc
- `$` means last line
- `d` means delete

The basic idea of `sed` is to link an action with pattern. `$ d` link `delete` with pattern `last line`. You can find more details on [sed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html).

---

1. https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html

Comment: I get    sed: 1: "test.docx": undefined label 'est.docx'